# How to retrieve list of all local audio files and its parameters properly?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

For now, I'm doing this with content resolver. Code:

```
private fun loadMedia(): List<LocalMusic> {
    val list = mutableListOf<LocalMusic>()

    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver

    val uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val selection = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC}!= 0"
    val sortOrder = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE} ASC"
    var i = 0
    contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder).use {
        if (it != null && it.count > 0) {
            while (it.moveToNext()) {
                val title = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE))
                // Android Studio shows a lint, which tells that MediaStore.MediaColumns.ARTIST 
                //requires API 30. But in Android Pie it works.
                val artist = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.ARTIST))
                //the same lint as described above(required api 29)
                val album = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.ALBUM))
                // This one is deprecated(fantastic, what to do?).
                val source = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA))
                val duration = it.getLong(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DURATION))
                list.add(LocalMusic(id = "$i", artist = artist, title = title, source = source,
                        album = album, duration = duration, image = "some uri"))
                i++
            }
        }
    }
    return list.toList()
}
```

So, there are some questions:

1. The main one. Should I use MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA to get URI anyway? I know that Google tells "sometimes you don't have permissions to work with storage, blah-blah, that's why it's deprecated", but is there a better way(I always have needed permissions)?
2. About "MediaStore.MediaColumns.ARTIST" and "MediaStore.MediaColumns.ALBUM". Why it requires API 30, if I found its usages in tutorials 5-6 years ago, though there was no API 30 at all? Because of support libraries, migrations, etc? Should I keep using it?